# How to do analytic continuation?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-continuation

I have some trouble with analytic continuation, even for a simple question. For example, I want to analytically continue the following function from negative real axis to the whole plane,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{|k|}}\exp \Big[-\int_x^0|k|dx\Big]$$
where $k=\alpha\sqrt{x}$. The answer is
$$\frac{e^{i\pi/4}}{\sqrt{\alpha\rho^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{i\phi/2}}}
\exp \Big[-i\frac{2}{3}\alpha\rho^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{i3\phi/2}\Big]$$
where $\rho$ is modula and $\phi$ is the argument for $x$ when we do analytical continuation. I know for $\phi=\pi$, the second expression goes back to the first one. I want to know how to find the second one, as detailed as possible, thank you.

---

Let me say what I have tried. First I write the function on negative axis as
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{|k|}}\exp \Big[-\int_x^0|k|dx\Big]
=\frac{1}{\alpha^{\frac{1}{2}}(-x)^{\frac{1}{4}}}
\exp\Big[-\frac{2}{3}\alpha(-x)^{\frac{3}{2}}\Big]
$$
Then I try to do analytical continuation. Naively if I replace
$$x\rightarrow z=\rho e^{i\phi} \,\,\,\hbox{and}\,\,\,-1=e^{i\pi}$$
I got the wrong answer. Analytical continuation
$$-x\rightarrow \rho e^{i(\phi-\pi)}$$
gives the right answer. I don't know why we should do the analytical continuation of $-x$ as a whole.

Comment: The "answer" involves symbols not in evidence in the question. What are $\rho$ and $\phi$ supposed to be? (and what do you get when you just carry out the integration, $-\int_x^0|k|\,dx$?)

Comment: Analytic continuation should result in a function of $z$ (or $x$, in your notation), not a function of modulus and argument separately. But you haven't told me whether you tried just doing the integration.

Comment: Sorry for my poor expression. I have tried to fix it.

Comment: This function will have a branch point at the origin. You cannot continue it analytically to the whole plane. Is this coming from the WKB approximation to the Airy equation?

Comment: Yes it is from WKB, but the author do the analytical continution rather than Airy.

Comment: Though there is the Stokes line difficulty, we can do analytical continuation from exponential small to exponential big solution, and it works.